# Why I have this particular error in my Atom reader: Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Old Webkit (Safari 4+, Chrome)

Tags: html, css

```
.btn {
    background: #11cdd4;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #11999e);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #11999e);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #11999e);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #11999e);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #11cdd4, #11999e);
    -webkit-border-radius: 8;
    -moz-border-radius: 8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #30e3cb;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #30e3cb, #2bc4ad);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #30e3cb, #2bc4ad);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #30e3cb, #2bc4ad);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #30e3cb, #2bc4ad);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #30e3cb, #2bc4ad);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: If you ask why I posted the code like that, it's because Stack Overflow wouldn't let me post the copied code from my Atom reader.

Comment: You've got some kind of linter that is stuck in 2013. Upgrade it, whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to support such old versions, check on caniuse.com to see what prefixes are needed.

https://caniuse.com/?search=linear-gradient states that some earlier versions (e.g. Safari 4) supported an earlier version of gradient: `-webkit-gradient`

You may like to add those in too if you need to pass the checking for old system's compatibility.

Comment: Guys, I solved the problem in a rather unorthodox way: I just added this line of code to both classes: background: -webkit-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #11999e); apparently the errors disappeared. What is the logic of this? Thanks for the answers by the way!

Comment: The answer is in my answer. It’s not unorthodox, you are just putting in what was an original version of the gradient value which was used by some of the older versions of browsers.